# Can mailbox locks be rekeyed?

Tags: lock, mailbox

I have two mailboxes: My primary home has a cluster mailbox with a standard CompX lock (it was replaced ~5 years ago, in case that's relevant), and my second home has a [standalone mailbox](https://a.co/d/0Y08dfc) that I own. I would like them both to use the same key. I know I can purchase a CompX lock online and it will probably fit in the keyhole for the Mail Boss mailbox, but is it also possible to rekey it to match my existing key? If so, is this something I can do myself or would I have to find a professional?

Comment: It depends on locale. Some places consider the Post Office the owner of the mailbox, and you'd need to check on changes with them.

Comment: Since I installed the mailbox myself I don't think that will be an issue. This question is mainly about practicality, not legality.

Comment: Have you looked closely at both of the mechanisms? It’s possible that they’re similar enough that you could buy two locks that are keyed alike for less than the cost of 1 plus a rekey.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to rekey lock barrels/mechanisms to use the same key if they are similar enough. You can call a locksmith to do it.  However, the cheaper way is to remove both the locks and take them into a lock smith.

If that does not look too easy, then take both keys into a locksmith and they may be able to tell you with more certainty.